# Do other human-like beings keep pets?

Tags: harry-potter

> Harry sped on, staring around, and soon the dwellings became more numerous; there were gardens of weed around some of them, and he even saw a pet grindylow tied to a stake outside one door.

I was just wondering whether other human-like creatures, like Centaurs keep pets like some of the Merpeople do.

Comment: Can you clarify this as to a specific secondary world? You seem to be focusing on the Wizarding World, and of course your tag of choice is HP. But please make sure your actual question is clear!

Comment: Harry assumes that the merpeople building is a home and the Gryndylow is a pet, but it might have been a secured area with a guard animal, like the Gringotts vault and dragon.

Comment: @elemtilas i disagree... i think you should be able to use common sense and just see the tag to realise that it's Harry Potter related, A.K.A i think the tag is enough

Comment: @elemtilas also, the question is completely clear! from my point of view.

Comment: we all know that hagrid keeps  pets, but do other human like creatures like centaurs keep pets??

Answer (score 4):

Hagrid is a half-human (half-giant) and we see him with various pets throughout the series, including (among others) a dog, a dragon, and a hippogriff.

Comment: While technically true I don't think OP was counting Hagrid as a "human-like being"

Comment: @user13267 When I posted my answer that’s not what the question said. It said “half human”, hence my answer begins by stating that Hagrid was half human and half giant.

Comment: I.e. the question was edited *after* my answer had already been posted.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7418/best-policy-when-edit-to-question-invalidates-the-answer